# Why "We've worked" can't be in the past?

Tags: phrases, tense, sentence, aspect

On Duolingo with the phrase "We've worked at this bakery since twenty eleven."
It doesn't accept 私たちは２０１１年からこのパン屋で働いていました. It says the correct answer is 私たちは2011年からこのパン屋で働いています

Why can't I use 働いていました?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My understanding of the English *"we **have worked** at `[place]` since `[time]`"* is that it describes an ongoing period -- the speaker began working there at `[time]`, and **still works there**.  If the speaker no longer worked there, I would expect them to say *"we **had worked**"* or even just *"we **worked**"* instead.

Because the speaker **still works there**, the Japanese phrase 「働【はたら】いていました」 is incorrect, since that ～てい(まし)た phrasing puts the action firmly in the past, as a completed event -- much like the English *"we **[had] worked**"*.